# Joomla multilanguage website redirect to corresponding page when click on flag

Tags: joomla, multilingual

I developed a Joomla! multi language website and working fine. But my problem is

Languages are English and Russian

When I was on an article in "English Page" and if I press that "Russian Flag" then the page will redirect to "Russian Home Page" other than "Russian ".

I am used "joomla native multi language facility" not any third party plugin.

The problem ruining my day

Please anyone help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the option Menu Associations in the plug-in "System - Language Filter" then you'll see a tab/slide in the menu items to associate menu items of other languages. [(This page can be useful)](http://multilingual-joomla-demo.cloudaccess.net/multi-lingual-steps-by-steps/39-new-in-1-7-associated-menu-items.html)